# Das Keyboard: M key stopped working properly

Tags: keyboard, cleaning

I have a das keyboard where the M key doesn't respond very well anymore, it is a bit random really..

Any ideas on how to clean the contact of the key so it *should* become more responsive again?

Comment: Sorry, no answer, but I'm a little jealous you've got a Das Keyboard. And your having this problem makes me a little less jealous.

Are you aware of any material that has gotten down into the mechanism?

Comment: @music2myear well there was quite some rubble in the keyboard i gotta admit, it was quite hard to clean that. But afaik there shouldn't be anything in there that is that small. And to make you a little bit more jealous again, i never had a better keyboard than this one :p

Comment: I shall just be happy for you, vicariously reveling in the fact that somewhere someone keyboards awesomely. :) BTW, have you tried alcohol on the contacts?

Comment: Hmm I used an airblower and now it seems fine.. or atleast I haven't had any problems so far, see a comment without any M's missing :d -- me happy nao ^^